# Linking two different content types with Views

Tags: 7, views, entities

I was wondering if one can link up the data with views in this way:

I have two content types (current_state & desired_state), both have 3 fields (location, item, quantity)

How can I join the data, so that it displays in a table like:

```
location | item | desired_quantity | current_quantity
```

I separated those content types because people with other permissions are allowed to edit them.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we have 2 **content types A and B** and want to display the content of content type B which have a **field reference** ie both A and B both have a common field.
then:

1. We simply **add B** to the **Filter Criteria** of the **view**.
2. Add an **nid of A** using **Contextual Filter** in the **advance Options**.
3. Add a **relationship of B** in **reverse order** in the **relationship field** in **advance options**.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Install the module [refernces](http://drupal.org/project/references)
2. Create a new view.
3. In the filter criteria section add the *second* content type which you want to get displayed.
4. Then in contextual filter section,add the field node reference with which you have linked the *second* content type.
5. Lastly, add a relationship of second content type in reverse order to get the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of relationship in views
tutorial i found [here](http://drupaleasy.com/blogs/ultimike/2009/07/using-views-relationships-arguments-attachments)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use the [References](http://drupal.org/project/references) module to create a relationship between the two nodes:

1. After installing References, add a node reference to one of the content types that you can use to point to the other one.
2. When creating the View, add a Relationship to the Referenced node.
3. You will then be able to see fields from the Referenced nodes when you go to add a Field to the View.

So if, for example, you added a node reference field on the current_quantity field to reference nodes of type desired_quantity, you can then add a Relationship to related desired_quantity nodes, then add a desired_quantity field to your View of current_quantity fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just display those two content types in the table (views) you don't need to relation between the content typs.

Just follow this steps:
1- Create new view (table display)    .
2- Filter : content type (current_state & desired_state).
3- Add your fields.
4- In format section click on settings beside "table".
5- You can display two field (each one from different content type) by selecting the field   in "COLUMN"    .
For example i have two fields (Car model,motor model) so from "COLUMN" of (motor model) select (car model) and they will display in one column.

6- Rename the first field (here in my example will rename the "Car model" field to "model").

Repeat step 5 and 6 for all fields you have in tour views.