# how to combine profiles and content types in a view

Tags: nodes, views, users

I'm trying to filter some content with a view, But view provides access to single entity type. I want to add the fields from `profiles` and `content types`. I'm wondering Is it possible to include both `contents` and `profiles` in a single view. I have spent lot of hours searching on web to find a solution for this, but didn't helped.

In this image I have selected `content` and it allows only to access the elements of `contents`. But I also want to `filter` the result by matching the contents of a `content type` and a `profile`.

[image: In this image view allows to select content]

Can anyone provide me a better solution to solve this problem....

Comment: in that case you can create two views and embed one view on other using this module, https://drupal.org/project/viewfield

Comment: did you check this post  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26898/linking-two-different-content-types-with-views

Comment: @shrish But my view only provides access to the fields of the selected profile.

Answer (score 0):

With Content-type view, you can use the "relationship" feature in Views and have access to the profile fields of the author of a certain node that is listed in the view. The same is valid for the Filters of that view.

To do so, edit your view and expand the "Advanced" settings section on the right. Then click on Relationships -> Add and add the relationship "Content: Author".

Hope that helps.