# Complex table with views?

Tags: views

I would like to build a table with Views like this:

> ```
>           | Header A| Header B | Header C
> ```
>
> **Header 1** | Value A1 | Value B1 | Value C1
>
> **Header 2** | Value A2 | Value B2 | Value C2

Header A, B, & C comes from 1st content type and number of columns is variable.

Header 1, 2 comes from 2nd content type and number of rows is variable.

Value A1, B1, C1, A2, B2, C2 comes from 3rd content type and content types are linked to each other with Node Reference fields.

How can I make this table with Views?

Thanks

Comment: This link may helps you http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26898/linking-two-different-content-types-with-views

Comment: Thank you for reply. But unfortunately it does not help. My view is much more complex. My both row and column Header cell's are variable.

Comment: I would like to make a table like in this wikipedia page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1968_Formula_One_season#1968_Drivers_Championship_final_standings

Comment: You can do this with the Views Matrix module: https://www.drupal.org/project/views_matrix . If this doesn't fit your needs, you will need to code. A very good answer can be found here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/94275/4387

Comment: I'm trying views matrix module. As far as I understand, this module is not very much configurable. For example I can only sort by name. I wish be able to sort with any other field. Anyway, if I create custom content type and fill information specially for this module, it will do what I need.
Thanks

Comment: No answer seems to be the right one for me. Matrix module solution might be the right one, if matrix module was a mature project. There are a lot of problems with matrix module. This could only be a workaround.

Comment: Views Matrix doesn't exactly solve the problem as it doesn't provide multiple row value. See my answer to this question here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/277994/83516