# Creating a view that uses fields from two content types

Tags: entities, views

I'm reeally struggling with this one. I just can't seem to wrap my head around the way Drupal and Views handles this pretty simple thing...

I have two content types:

- **Card**
- **Card Content**

**Card** has the following fields:

- *Title*
- *Body*
- *Display Order*
- *Linked ID*

**Card Content** has the following fields:

- *Title*
- *Body*
- *Linked ID*

In Views, I would like to display:

- **Card Content** - *Title*
- **Card Content** - *Body*
- **Card** - *Display Order*

If I were to write this as an SQL statement, it would be simple:

```
SELECT a.title, a.body, b.display_order
FROM card_content AS a
  INNER JOIN card AS b
    ON a.linked_id = b.linked_id
```

How do I achieve this?

**Things to note**: I originally had the *Linked ID* as a select box, taken from a set of predefined taxonomy terms. I have since migrated these to *entity-reference*s, that pull the data from the taxonomy terms (if that makes sense)?

**EDIT**: Okay, to clarify things a little...

*Linked ID* is a select box that's linked to a taxonomy vocabulary. This is purely to limit what a user can input.

As requested, here are screenshots of my **Card** and **Card Content**.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have any relation ( node reference or etc ) between this two content types?

Comment: Do you mean like the linked ID, contained in both content types? That comes from the taxonomy?

Comment: No, a relation that connect this two content type to each other, I mean something like entity references(or node references) ?

Comment: What exactly is "Linked ID" supposed to represent?  It seems as though you're trying to associate Cards with Card Content, but you mention that Linked ID references a taxonomy term for some reason.

Comment: @zhilevan no I don't. As I mentioned, I changed the _Linked ID_ to an entity-reference, but I don't really know what I'm doing, nor what an entity-reference is...

Comment: @Jack_Hu would you please provide 2 screen shot of field management of your content types?

Comment: @Jack_Hu you should use an entityreference field to let your Card Content nodes directly reference Card nodes (or vice-versa) rather than trying to do it through taxonomy terms.  This will greatly simplify your View.

Comment: look at this question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26898/linking-two-different-content-types-with-views  it may help you.

Comment: @Jack_Hu tnx for your screenshots, I answer your question , if you need more details or help comment below it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a `entity reference` field in **Card** name it as "card content ref"( reference it to "Card Content" content type ) , then in your views, add relation to "card content ref" then in your field list "Card Content - Title" and "Card Content - Body" field exists.

Also for tutorial and learning more about Realation between two content types read [this article](http://drupaleasy.com/blogs/ultimike/2009/07/using-views-relationships-arguments-attachments)

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to use [entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference)

Below is the youtube link which will provide you step by step explanation of using entity reference module with views.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Pdii7aFIvc

Answer (score 1):

You can use this module..suitable for your requirement https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference

Answer (score 0):

We have 2 content types of A and B:

1. We add content type B to the Filter Criteria of the view.
2. Add an nid of content type A using Contextual Filter in the advance Options.
3. Add a relationship of content type B in reverse order in the relationship field in advance options.